# Disqus API: retrieve "parent" post permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, disqus

Some time ago I wrote this snippet for my WordPress install to get the 5 latest comments to show up as a list:

```
<?php $comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=5'); ?>
<ul style="font-size:5px">
    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment) { ?>
        <li style="font-size:10px">
            <div style="float:left;margin-right:3px"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, $size = '35' ); ?></div>
            <em style="font-size:12px"><?php echo strip_tags($comment->comment_author); ?></em> (<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/?p=<?php echo($comment->comment_post_ID); ?>/#comment-<?php echo($comment->comment_ID); ?>">link</a>)<br>
            <?php echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 35 ); ?>...
        </li>
    <?php }  ?>
</ul>
```

Today I installed Disqus, and the links to comments is changed. Same comment, before the link was `http://mydomain.com/?p=760/#comment-4986`, now it's `http://mydomain.com/?p=760/#comment-1364246021`.

Since links were not working anymore I wrote this snippet to get the 5 latest posts through Disqus APIs. It works fine. I get author and comment content.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    $key="MY_PUBLIC_KEY";
    $forum="MY_FORUM_NAME";
    $limit = '5';

    $endpoint = 'http://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/list.json?api_key='.urlencode($key).'&forum='.$forum.'&limit='.$limit;

    $j=0;
    listposts($endpoint,$j);

    function listposts($endpoint,$j) {

    // Standard CURL
    $session = curl_init($endpoint);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);

    // Decode JSON data
    $results = json_decode($data);
    if ($results === NULL) die('Error parsing json');

    // Comment response
    // print($data);

    // Comment response
    $comments = $results->response;

    // Cursor for pagination
    $cursor = '&cursor=' . $results->cursor->next;

    $i=0;
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        $name = $comment->author->name;
        $comment = $comment->message;
        // Get more data...

        echo "<em>".$name."</em><br/>";
        echo $comment."<br/>";
        $i++;
    }

}
?>
```

I'd like to get also the link of the WordPress post the comments "belongs" to!
For example the last comment was posted on a blog post with id=44. I'd like to have that ID or better the complete permalink (e.g. domain.com/?p=44). I searched through their APIs but I can't find something to retrieve post permalink/id.

**EDIT:** Ok, seems I need to mix [posts/list](https://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/list/) with [threads/list](https://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/list/).
But I don't know how to extract from the first foreach (posts/list) the threads names, store them in an array and and put it in the other foreach (this time for threads/list) to obtain (for each) response->link. Seems like I need to have 5 different requests (for every one I need a different endpoint as the thread changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `posts/list` endpoint, you can expand the `thread` object which should give you the information you need. **Just add** `related=thread` to your request.

In the response, `thread` should now be an object instead of a string ID. Because you're using Wordpress, there should be an `identifiers` array in the `thread` object that looks similar to this:

`"identifiers": [ "44 http://domain.com/?p=44" ]`